# Chrome looks messed up

Tags: google-chrome, macbook-pro, osx-el-capitan

The folders in the favorites bar look gray. They used to look blue, and I don't know what I've done to create this.

I've reset Chrome to default, but it does not restore this.
On my 2nd account on my Macbook it looks the way it should be (blue).

What can I do to fix this?

[image: folders]

Edit: I just figured out that in the "manager" it looks good:

[image: folders the way they should be]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out it's the "material design" in the 'chrome://flags' section which can be turned off.

[This page helped me to find it.](http://www.howtogeek.com/266280/how-to-turn-chromes-new-material-design-on-and-off/)